# Japanese Stack Overflow is 2014 years old

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com

[image]

This is clearly a bug. Somewhere. Somehow.

Comment: Oh, it's Japanese. \*facepalm\*

Comment: Fix incoming in 2006-2008 years.